# Using Pickle object like an API call

Tags: python, pickle

I trained a NaiveBayes classifier to do elementary sentiment analysis. The model is 208MB . I want to load it only once and then use Gearman workers to keep calling the model to get the results.   It takes rather long time to load it only once. How do i load the model only once and then keep calling it ?

Some code , hope this helps :

```
import nltk.data
c=nltk.data.load("/path/to/classifier.pickle")
```

This remains as the loader script.

Now i have a gearman worker script which should *call* this "c" object and then classify the text.

```
c.classify('features')
```

This is what i want to do . 
Thanks.

Comment: You could serialize Python objects to files and then load them. The problem is that model is too large?

Comment: Yeah , if i do that, then i need not load it anyway. I need to load it just once and keep calling it. Like calling a server .

Comment: Not to throw another package into your mix, but I have had the need to cache the results of expensive SQL queries that will change at long intervals by loading them in a cherrypy daemon and retrieving them as JSON-encoded values. The SQL calls were done only once per interval, when the interval had passed, the given query was performed again and all cached data flushed. I should imagine you can do something similar here.

Comment: did you tried exploring the option of loading your classifier once on the start of the application and after that keep using the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to use pickle, than that's the answer

```
    import pickle
    class Model(object):
        #some crazy array of data
        def getClass(sentiment)
            #return class of sentiment

    def loadModel(filename):
        f = open(filename, 'rb')
        res = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        return res

    def saveModel(model, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(model, f)
        f.close()
    m = loadModel('bayesian.pickle')
```

if it's a problem to load large object in such a way, than I don't know whether pickle could help

Comment: Thanks for the solution , but no. What i am looking for is to load the model once and then keep calling it. Let me upload the code to make it kinda clear.